Would a species living underground be heavier for their height than humans?
A humanoid species lives underground in the earth's crust. They spend the majority of their childhood underground, then live above ground during adolescence and early adulthood before returning back underground to have kids. (Those who are above ground are farmers and provide for the families and nobility that live underground, craftsmen live above or below depending on what they make and who it is for).
They are much shorter than the average human (about 3 feet 7 inches-4 feet 3 inches or 109.22cm-129cm). They also have an increased muscle mass particularly in their neck and back due to having horns and a tail.They have a larger body weight/mass to height ratio when compared to a human's.
What is a plausible reason for them to have a greater proportional  body mass if they also spend time above ground?
(I am learning how to format/ask questions so suggestions and critics are appreciated)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

They could easily be heavier for their height if they were on average stouter than humans, but that's a very different question than "density".

I've updated the title, but paused before updating the body of the question.   I'm assuming you mean greater proportionate body mass, not greater body mass fullstop.  It'd be hard for a 3'8" humanoid to outmass a 6'5" human.

For some reason it's popular for new authors to visit this site to ask us to make a worldbuilding decision for them, usually under the guise of "science must know the answer." Do you want them to have greater body mass? Do you not want them to have that? Make the decision yourself - then we can help you rationalize it. But the truth is, there is no guaranteed right answer. Science won't solve this problem for you save as a story-based choice. (We close questions for being story-based.)

Underground does not dictate heft
There’s zero causal relationship that I know of between a species being above/below ground and its average weight. It is hard to prove a negative, and I cannot cite a source for a negative statement. Species mass is driven by available calories and the presence of competition for those calories. More calories generally supports larger sizes; more competition generally supports smaller sizes.There’s some correlation of bigger size to more specialized diet.
Nothing I’ve ever heard of and nothing I found while searching tonight suggests underground is a factor. So make whatever call you want, at least as far as location is concerned.
Out of curiosity, what made you think that the two aspects were related?

"what made you think that the two aspects were related?" Some sort of subconscious association with traditional fantasy dwarfs being depicted as short but also broad, stout and (somewhat for their size) musclebound would be my guess? .. We can probably blame Tolkien and Gygax

I my head living underground might cause genetic preference towards being short and stout like dwarves and thus when building underground less space would need to be excavated when building. Plus most animals that live underground like moles, badgers, etc, tend to have shorter legs compared to their overall size.

Short, yes, but not necessarily stout. If calories are meager, you’ll have wispy dwarves.

Depends on how far underground you go. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preliminary_reference_Earth_model shows that gravity increases as you go down towards the core. Higher gravity could lead to shorter more stout creatures. But these creatures would also need to handle the massive increase in temperature.

While just living underground doesn't affect average weight (like SRM already layed out), there are some environmental conditions that MIGHT apply to an underground world (it is your underground world, so it is your decision how it looks like) and that COULD be used to rationalize those Sirens evolving to be heavier (for their size).

"No wide open spaces" mean less running around. Running around when you are heavier takes more energy than when you are lighter.
"Requirement to dig through massive materials". Digging through heavy materials and heaving big rocks out of collapsed tunnels takes a lot of strength, aka muscle mass. Sirens being adapted to their environment might have evolved to have more muscle mass than a human of similar size. We can already see this in humans, more muscled humans are heavier for their size than "weaker" humans. Muscle mass is also denser than fat so this wouldn't neccessarily make them "wider".
"extreme Temperatures" fat is a very good insulation. Usually it is used by earthly creatures to prevent losing body heat but could also work to keep heat out of the body. If living in harsh temperatures, maybe even changing from one extreme to the other, the sirens might have evolved a thicker layer of fat underneath their skin to insulate them from sudden temperatur changes.

As for the placeholder I wonder why you didn't go with "dwarf" as a placeholder. I mean come on, you have a humanoid race that is smaller, heavier and lives deep underground....

Point 3. Underground temperatures are normally pretty constant and not particularly extreme (unless you go deep enough, when it gets really hot, which is the reverse of the necessary conditions to encourage lots of insulating fat) and confined well insulated spaces with organisms living in them (houses, homes.. caves with a large population of dwarves ) can be expected to be quite warm, due to body heat with nowhere to go, a cave will feel cool (compared to) outdoors on a warm day because it doesn't get direct sunlight but it's not a 'harsh climate' and can be warmer in winter than outside.

@Pelinore i am aware that this is the case on earth. But a fantasy world might feature  "an ancient magical icecream stand" that was buried in the depths of earth close to the region where the sirens live. This icecream stand eats up heat of the surrounding area to condense the energy into tasty icecream for the long dead masters of magic. Or any other environmental reason that OP can come up with. Locate the only food with vitamin C in the frost area of the icecream stand and you have evolutionary pressure of "go into the frost zone regulary or die of scurvy"

Sure ice houses are a thing and some natural ice caves have existed for a very long time, enough rock is really good at insulating stuff  but absent magic you gotta put the ice there to start with somehow, it's not in and of itself a normal feature of underground, ice caves are normally near the surface with some way for the seed ice to get blown in or something as I understand it.

@Pelinore maybe there is some gigantic underground river that transport the heat back to the surface. Or a big reservoir of elements that react together in a strong endothermal reaction. My point is: it would be an environmental factor that COULD drive evolution in the desired direction. How the cold comes down there (or rather the heat goes away) would be up to the descretion of OP or topic of a further question.

"This icecream stand eats up heat of the surrounding area to condense the energy into tasty icecream for the long dead masters of magic" 1st edition AD&D Unearthed Arcana, Cantrips, some mage enchants a pebble and casts permanenced versions of Chill, Dampen, Flavour and Sweeten on it (for some reason) and leaves it lying around in a cave somewhere  that'd do it

The environment selects for being shapped like a sausage- potatoe. As in keep the heat together, while at the same time be optimized for the tunnels you dig, you move through. So the environment selects for diameter/shape. The environment is also - calorie poor (no sunglight, the source of nearly all calories), so on average minimal mass is accumulated before more instances are created.
In nature, size is mostly a feature of seasonal changes (bears gorging up before going into hibernation) or a result of breeding success (hormonal bloat by dominant males). Only one of two applies to an deep underground environment, independent food-sourced from the overworld.
